# How to handle cross browser and device compatibility for MediaRecorder and Audio control

Tags: audio, html5-audio, mediarecorder

My web app needs to support recording of audio using a web interface and then subsequent playback of the same audio files.

My prelim analysis shows that chrome supports “audio/webm” and safari supports “audio/mp4” for recording audio using the MediaRecorder. This would have been fine but HTML5 AUDIO component on these browsers has the same format limitation and this is causing a device/OS fragmentation.

I am using AWS as my application's backend.

Is there a way to get around this browser segmentation.